# Qual a diferença projetos "master detail application" e "web view application"?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

Existe alguma diferença no Xamarin entre projetos *master detail application* e *web view application*?

Estou iniciado um novo projeto em Xamarin iPhone.

Comment: O ideal seria usar o Single Page application para inicar um novo projeto, por ser o projeto inicial mais simples, com menos coisas para se alterar.

Answer (score 2):

**Master detail application** quer dizer que será criado um projeto base já montado com um *storyboard* que contém um TableViewController (master) e um UIViewController (detail). Significa que você tem uma tabela e ao clicar em uma de suas entradas irá exibir os detalhes dessa entrada. Você deve popular a tabela e configurar o layout da tela de detalhes.

Veja aqui a explicação do xamarin: http://docs.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/general/storyboard/storyboard_a_tableview/

Veja a explicação da apple:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html

Já sobre **web view application**, eu não vi a possibilidade de criar um projeto como esse, mas acredito que seja um projeto também já montado com um UIViewController que dentro possua uma UIWebView. Uma webView é como um browser dentro do seu aplicativo. É usado se você quiser carregar webPages sem precisar sair do aplicativo (também é possível mandar o Safari carregar, o que iria sair).

Então, é preciso ver o que você precisa: carregar webpages ou popular uma tabela e exibir seus detalhes quando uma entrada da tabela é tocada.